# Kotlin generic function variance

Tags: kotlin

I have a class like follow:

```
class Weekend<T : Any> {
   
   fun <R> equal(property: KProperty1<T, R>, value: R?) {
      ...
      return this
   }
}
```

and use the class like follow:

```
Weekend<User>().equal(User::name, "username")
```

in this case, `User.name` is a string property, and "username" is also a string. But if I write the code like `Weekend<User>().equal(User::name, 22)`, kotlin will not give errors, because `string` and `Int` has the same parent `Compareble`.

Is there any way to tell kotlin the second param `value` must be a `string` here? (I know `Weekend<User>().equal<String>(User::name, 22)` will work, but I want a simple way to do this.)

Comment: The answer @Sweeper points to provides the answer as to why this is currently not possible, in fact the issue tracker uses an almost identical example.

Answer (score 0):

If the second param must be a string just set it as `String?`

```
fun equal(property: KProperty1<T, String>, value: String?)
```

Comment: I want second param type same to the second generic type